# Stopping a while statement

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have been assigned in my intro to computer science class to write a program that will print out a number that the user is asked to enter (20-99).  I have been able to do that, and have created an error message if the user doesn't enter a number in this range. The issue I am having is when a number out of range is entered, the error message displays, but for some reason the program continues and still prints out a english number. I have been trying to figure out how to get the program to stop at the error message, but I have not been able to figure it out. Here is what I currently have.

```
a=int(input('Pick a number between 20 through 99:'))

b=a//10

c=a%10

while a<20 or a>99:

    print('Error, enter number between 20 and 99:')
    break

while a>20 or a<99:

    if b==2:
        print('The number is Twenty',end=' ')
    elif b==3:
        print('The number is Thirty',end=' ')
    elif b==4:
        print('The number is Fourty',end=' ')
    elif b==5:
        print('The number is Fifty',end=' ')
    elif b==6:
        print('The number is Sixty',end=' ')
    elif b==7:
        print('The number is Seventy',end=' ')
    elif b==8:
        print('The number is Eighty',end=' ')
    else:
        print('The number is Ninety',end=' ')
    if c==1:
        print('One')
    elif c==2:
        print('Two')
    elif c==3:
        print('Three')
    elif c==4:
        print('Four')
    elif c==5:
        print('Five')
    elif c==6:
        print('Six')
    elif c==7:
        print('Seven')
    elif c==8:
        print('Eight')
    else:
        print('Nine')       
    break
```

Comment: First, thanks for being honest that it's homework. You could use a condition `if` statement to test if the variable entered is between 20 and 99 instead of a loop.

Comment: You have a loop with an unconditional `break`. That's basically just an `if` statement. If you want to actually keep asking for a new number, you'll need to do that in the loop. It looks like you need to review your textbook's section on loops and input checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second conditional you want `and` not `or`

```
while a>20 and a<99:
```

also use `if` because it will infinite loop if you don't

Answer (score 0):

You have confused "while" with "if".  You need an "if" statement here; "while" is for things you intend to repeat.

Also, note that a>20 or a<99 is *always* true; any number is one or the other.  I believe you wanted an "and" here, which makes this merely the "else" clause of the "if" statement.

Finally, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the "end=" in your first bank of print statements.  This is a syntax error.

Comment: end= isn't a syntax error in python3. when you have end=" " and use print it puts a space at the end instead of newline

Comment: That does it! Thank you! But the reason for the "end= " is so that the first part of the number and the second part of the number are on one line, and not two.

Comment: Thanks; we're still on Python 2.7 here.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the break statement inside of the while loop. This means that when you reach that statement, you leave the while loop. So no matter what, your function will leave the loop. A good sign that your while loop is not correct or out of place is if you call a break at the end. Here is a better way.

```
while True:
    a=int(input('Pick a number between 20 through 99:'))
    if a > 20 and a < 99:
        break;
    else:
        print("Error, enter number between 20 and 99")
```

What happens is that the loop goes on indefinitely. Once the correct input is entered, it breaks from the loop. If the input is not correct, it just loops again.

---

Even though you didn't ask about it, I'm going to comment on the other half as well. First, your condition doesn't make sense. All numbers are either over 20 or under 99. You need to use an `and` so that BOTH must be true. However, the other part is that you don't even need this conditional statement. We already know that we are in this limit. That's what we made sure of in our previous while loop. Lastly, as stated before, the while itself isn't need. If you want to use a conditional that you only use one time, just use an `if` statement. While is mean for looping and forces you to have a break statement at the end if you will only ever use it once. Here is your completed code:

```
while True:
    a=int(input('Pick a number between 20 through 99:'))
    if a > 20 and a < 99:
        break;
    else:
        print("Error, enter number between 20 and 99")

b=a//10

c=a%10

if b==2:
    print('The number is Twenty',end=' ')
elif b==3:
    print('The number is Thirty',end=' ')
elif b==4:
    print('The number is Fourty',end=' ')
elif b==5:
    print('The number is Fifty',end=' ')
elif b==6:
    print('The number is Sixty',end=' ')
elif b==7:
    print('The number is Seventy',end=' ')
elif b==8:
    print('The number is Eighty',end=' ')
else:
    print('The number is Ninety',end=' ')
if c==1:
    print('One')
elif c==2:
    print('Two')
elif c==3:
    print('Three')
elif c==4:
    print('Four')
elif c==5:
    print('Five')
elif c==6:
    print('Six')
elif c==7:
    print('Seven')
elif c==8:
    print('Eight')
else:
    print('Nine') `enter code here`
```